# Libre Office Writer macro to conditionally change font color

Tags: libreoffice-basic

I am on Libre Office 6.0. I generated a macro to change the font color of selected text to 'Blue 3'. It works fine.

What I want the macro to do is select the entire document and change the font color to 'Blue 3' for any blue text that is some other color of blue.

The issue is that I converted some documents and the hyperlinks are blue but an off-color of blue. Highlighting and correcting multiple hyperlinks surrounded by black text is a laborious process.

```
sub ChangeToBlue3
    dim document   as object
    dim dispatcher as object
    document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
    dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args1(0).Name = "Color"
    args1(0).Value = 255
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Color", "", 0, args1())
end sub
```